# Can the subtitle of an Area 51 proposal be edited during the commitment phase?

Tags: discussion, area-51, edits

I created a "Dermatology and Dermatopathology" proposal at:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22278/dermatology-and-dermatopathology

With that being said, I wanted to know if during the commitment stage a moderator might be able to edit the subtitle of the proposal to something a bit more inclusive. If this is possible, I wanted to know if someone would change...

"Proposed Q&A site for expert dermatologist and dermatopathologists"

...to...

"Proposed Q&A site for expert dermatologist and dermatopathologists, researchers, medical students, wound care specialists, nurses, and other skin enthusiasts"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds reasonable. Done.

> ### Dermatology and Dermatopathology
>
> Proposed Q&A site for expert dermatologist and dermatopathologists, medical students, wound care specialists, nurses, and other skin enthusiasts

Comment: why not make it possible for the proposer to make that change themselves?

Comment: @WikiSpeedia: It may already be possible. They simply need to switch to the `definition` tab to have access to the definition tools.

Comment: aha, that sounds great, thanks.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino what do you mean by "it _may_ already be possible"?  i'm having the same issue as Wikis but i don't have definition tools to edit the name of my proposal. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25641/managers-and-leaders the group decided to change it to "management and leadership". thank you!